# Re-render a component when a prop is updated (Inertia)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I'm passing a prop from a controller to a page

```
return Inertia::render('Dashboard/Restaurant', [
        'restaurant' => $restaurant
    ]);
```

Then inside of the 'Dashboard/Restaurant' I have 2 child components that are receiving the $restaurant as a prop. One is a form and the other one is a card where you can visualize the data.

When the form is submitted, I just store the values in the DB and return to the same page:

```
return Redirect::route('restaurant');
```

In order to update the prop after the form is submitted, I have created a computed value in the parent component:

```
setup(props) {
    const restaurant = computed(() => props.restaurant)
    return {
        restaurant,
    };
},
```

However, if I want to update the card after the form is submitted, I created another computed value in the child component that is the exact same code as before.

In this way my goal to display the updated date after form submission is achieved. But, is the correct way to update a prop from parent to child? I'm using the exact same code in 2 places and that makes me thing that there should a be a solution for it.

This is the template of the parent component:

```
<template>
<Admin>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap">
        <div class="w-full lg:w-8/12 px-4">
            <CardRestaurantSettings :restaurant="restaurant" />
        </div>
        <div class="w-full lg:w-4/12 px-4">
            <CardProfile :restaurant="restaurant" />
        </div>
    </div>
</Admin>
```

Comment: props are reactive already, so you don't need to wrap them in a computed.

Comment: If I remove the computed property seems that they do update but no re-render. Therefore, showing the card updated after form submission doesn't work. DB gets updated tho. @Thomas